# drop frames with mediacodec encoder and input surface

Tags: android, encoding, native, android-mediacodec

I tried to drop frames as explained in this post: [MediaCodec KEY_FRAME_RATE seems to be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336604/mediacodec-key-frame-rate-seems-to-be-ignored/)
But the result I have is not very good because frames drops from 60 to less than 10 fps.
I didn't find how to control properly the number of dropped frames and can't understand why it drops so much frames (it should drop half frames, so I should end with 30 fps).
Any idea why I have such result, and how to control properly the number of dropped frames ?
Thanks you very much.

Comment: Can you include a small snippet of the code involved?  Is it dropping too many frames, or are the PTS timestamps getting skewed?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found my issue, it was not exactly related to this but thank you because your answer helped me to see it from another point of view.