# KEY_FRAME_RATE is being ignored in Android

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am using MediaCodec to encode video from the camera into h264. I used to have 30 fps and this is the output I was getting, but now I need to switch to 25fps and the MediaFormat line:

```
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
```

is not working: I always get 30fps regardless of this value (I even tried putting 5 fps and the video is still smooth).

Is there anything else I need to do to achieve my desired fps value?

Answer (score 1):

MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE does not tell the Encoder to drop frames.
[Visit for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22339431/7707785) .

To reduce the overall framerate you have to either drop frames manually, correct the timestamps to match your desired fps (probably not what since the result will be a longer video)

A very basic but good doc on how to manipulate framerates (sadly mostly increasing the rate) can be found [here](https://documentation.apple.com/en/cinematools/usermanual/index.html#chapter=2%26section=5%26tasks=true)

Greetings

Comment: @MichelReap You can correct the timestamps as the frames are fed into the MediaMuxer through writeSampleData().

Comment: wouldnt this make the video choppy?