# MediaCodec h264 encoder outputs large raw stream

Tags: java, android, h.264, android-mediacodec, encoder

I'm using MediaCodec in an Android app to encode frames from a Usb camera and then feed that raw stream to mp4parser to create mp4(API level is 16).

Everything works really good on many devices, but i have issues with Galaxy S3 (I9300).

The problem is that when i send frames to the encoder for 1 minute, sometimes i get a very large output from the encoder.

The size range is between 2.5MB-20MB.
This problem gets worse on longer clips, for example 7 minutes range is 9MB-120MB.

Is that normal?

I tried to capture the same scene, but still got different results.

The encoder settings:

```
Codec: OMX.SEC.AVC.Encoder
Color Format: 21
KEY_FRAME_RATE: 8.77
KEY_BIT_RATE: ~880Kbit
```

One more thing, when sending the frames to the encoder i'm using:

```
mediaVideoCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, FrameData.length, computePresentationTime(frameCounter), 0);
```

and the function

```
private long computePresentationTime(int frameIndex) {
    return (long)(132 + (frameIndex * (1000000f / 8.77f)));
}
```

The encoding is done in a background thread, so i'm not sure i can use system time here, unless the producer saves the frame and time.
Is that correct and what does 132 represents?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The "132" means that the code was copied from [the CTS test](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/EncodeDecodeTest.java#1128), which generates the video it encodes.  The test code is creating a series of frames with a constant frame rate.  As part of an effort to determine that the timestamps are being passed through unmodified, and not generated internally by the codec, a small offset is added.

At 880Kbps, you'd expect (880/8)*(7*60)/1024 = 45MB.  Most encoders do a pretty good job of matching the desired rate.  I've seen this go bad when the timestamps on the frames don't match the frame rate (e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661391/)), but since you're generating the time stamps I'm not sure why that would be.

Ideally the timestamp comes from the camera, not a generated value or the system time.  Otherwise you have no way of knowing if a frame was dropped near the source.

MediaCodec has [many problems](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q9) in Android 4.1 (API 16) that were resolved in Android 4.3 (API 18).  What device and version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: Thank you for your response fadden.
The device is Samsung Galaxy S3 running 4.4.2, and the camera produces 384x288 frames at ~8.77 fps.
The problem doesn't occur on Nexus 5 (6.0.1) and Sony Xperia Z3 (5.1.1).