# MediaCodec encode data too big

Tags: android, encoding, android-mediacodec

I use MediaCodec to encode camera data, and when I use it on a device named Vivo X5 Pro(android 5.0, API 21),the data's size MediaCodec encoded is above 90000, and normally on other devices the size is about 15000.However I change the params of media format,it also dose't work.
I also find that when I get the format with method MediaCodec.getOutputFormat() on Vivo X5 Pro(android 5.0, API 21),it has 7 data, one more than other normal case,it named "buffer-size" and value is 1048576,is this will influence the MediaCodec encode? How can I use Vivo X5 Pro(android 5.0, API 21) to encode a normal data size? Thank for help!!!

```
    MediaCodec mEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC);
    MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC, 320, 568);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 320 * 568 * 2);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 20);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 320 * 568);
```

PS:However I change the params Vivo X5 Pro(android 5.0, API 21) encode data size still above 90000.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you pass proper timestamps for the input frames, in the right unit (microseconds), otherwise the encoder can allocate too few/many bits per frame - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20663056/3115956 for a longer explanation of this.

Have you tried lowering/raising the bitrate parameter to see if it actually changes the output size? Otherwise the encoder might just be broken in the sense that it doesn't respect this parameter. (Also, the size of the first output packet might not totally reflect what the total average bitrate of the output stream is. So even if the first frame might be a bit too big, the later ones can potentially make up for it.)

Comment: It seems be opposite case with mine.My case is too big,his is too small.And I ever changed the params,but it dose not work in Vivo X5 Pro(the size not be lower),but it works in the other devices.T_T

Comment: Is it only the size of the first buffer that is too big, or are they all too big? If you change the bitrate, do the later buffers also stay the same size or do they change (while the first one remains big)?

Comment: all too big,and if I change the bitrate,the size has no change